# How to restore a mysql xml database file from mysql command line?

Tags: xml, powershell, mysql

I am running Windows XP, using the MySQL shell and PowerShell (MySQL 5.5), using XAMPP for Windows.

I have an XML file which I've placed in E:\xampp\mysql\bin for convenience.  I can run .\mysqldump.exe and .\mysql.exe but don't seem to be able to find the correct syntax for the type of XML file I'm using.

The XML file is laid out like this:

```
<mysqldump>
<database name="export">
<table_structure name="export_rental_2006_property">
<field Field="id" Type="bigint(20)" Null="NO" Key="" Default="" Extra=""/>
<field Field="name" Type="varchar(255)" Null="NO" Key="" Default="" Extra=""/>
```

...and so on, with "table_data" tags, "row" tags, and "field" tags with name= attributes etc.

Just to let you know, I have no way of changing the export format - this is what I have to import.  I've looked around and nothing I've tried from various tutorials and the MySQL website seemed to have worked.  Maybe I'm getting the procedure wrong.

If anybody has experience with this, help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is a `load xml` query you could try, but there isn't a native method of reloading an xml dump: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2010/04/restoring-xml-formatted-mysql-dumps.html

Comment: I found this within 90 seconds of doing a Google search: http://code.google.com/p/mysqldump-x-restore/ based on the fact I was able to find there is no native method within 90 seconds i have to downvote this question because what appears to be a complete lack of knowlege on the subject by the author.