# Import MySQL XML Dump?

Tags: mysql, phpunit

I have dumped a MySQL database (all tables) for use with [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html) using this command:

`mysqldump --xml -t -u [username] --password=[password] [database] > /path/to/file.xml`

I need to modify the test data, so I need to re-import it back into the database so I can work on it with MySQL workbench.

What is the command to reimport it back into a specified database?

And no, it's not as simple as [LOAD XML](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-xml.html), that works on a table by table basis, but this export has all tables in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**, there is no built in way present to restore a XML formatted dump file. You can check this blog [Restoring XML-formatted MySQL dumps](http://rpbouman.blogspot.in/2010/04/restoring-xml-formatted-mysql-dumps.html) for information on this as well as this existing post [How to restore a mysql xml database file from mysql command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313992/how-to-restore-a-mysql-xml-database-file-from-mysql-command-line)

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.

Comment: I wrote a script that will restore this. It's not nearly as good as a dump file because a number of things cannot be restored from an XML dump (table strcture, for example). But this is good enough: https://github.com/mjmunger/XMLDumpRestore